# Visit uk visa 2 years

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

I have a valid uk visit visa that will expire in 2020 , will i be able to visit the uk for 6 months and return back to my home country then after a month visit the uk again for another 6 months and so on? 
My husband is a british citizen so i am staying with him for 2 years visa and i am planning to return to my country every  6 months but the question is that i heard that i can stay only for total of 6 months the whole two years..

Can someone confirm pls?

Comment: You can't use a visitor visa to live in the UK. The border officers will almost certainly believe that you're living in the UK if you do this.

Answer (score 6):

**This will almost certainly not be allowed**

The [rules for the Standard Visitor visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa) say you **cannot**:

> live in the UK for long periods of time through frequent visits

[Guidance for border control officers](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/673351/Visit-guidance-v7.0EXT.PDF) (page 17) says:

> There is no specified maximum period which an individual can spend in the UK in
>   any period such as ‘6 months in 12 months’. However, if it is clear from an
>   individual’s travel history that they are making the UK their home you should refuse
>   their application.

The same document refers to "the individual spending more time in the UK than in their home country" as being a particular problem.

My interpretation is that if you attempt to spend more time in the UK than at home you will almost certainly be refused, and you may be refused with even less than that. If you want to stay with your husband you should immediately apply for a family visa. Not only will that allow you to eventually join your husband, but it will lend credibility to the idea that you will not try 'go underground' and try to stay with him illegally.

Answer (score 2):

There's no specific rule about the frequency and duration of visits. However, there is a requirement that you observe the terms of your visa. In this case, your visitor visa precludes you from living in the UK. If an immigration officer suspects that you're trying to make the UK your home by frequent lengthy visits he will deny you entry. This will make it much harder to get any sort of visa in the future.

If you want to live in the UK you should apply for the correct visa. Ask questions about that on [Expatriates](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com)